# How can i fix textrel issue in aarch64

Tags: assembly, elf, arm64

I tried to compile a open source [project](https://github.com/beehive-lab/mambo) which has assembly code on Android for aarch64 architecture.

The error message I got in compile step is

> aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: creating a DT_TEXTREL in a shared object.

In order to use `scanelf` to investigate what exactly cause the problem in shared object, I add the link flag `-Wl,--no-fatal-warnings` to generate a textrel shared object.

Follow the guide [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/Textrels_Guide) I found the code cause the problem.

Below is scanelf result

```sh
$ scanelf -qT ./build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/mambo
  mambo: (memory/data?) [0x7D20] in (optimized out: previous abort_self_signal) [0x7D10]
  mambo: (memory/data?) [0x7D28] in (optimized out: previous $d) [0x7D20]
  ./build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/mambo
```

And below is objdump result

```
$ aarch64-linux-android-objdump -d ./build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/mambo |grep -E "(7d20|7d28)"
    5d34:       92407d28        and     x8, x9, #0xffffffff
    6a9c:       93407d28        sxtw    x8, w9
    6e40:       0a887d20        and     w0, w9, w8, asr #31
    7ba4:       58000be3        ldr     x3, 7d20 <abort_self_signal+0x10>
    7cd4:       580002a3        ldr     x3, 7d28 <abort_self_signal+0x18>
    7d20:       00003f8c        .word   0x00003f8c
    7d28:       000052f8        .word   0x000052f8
```

And I locate the source code finally, did I have some mistakes?

```
// ...
  CBZ X0, abort_self_signal

// ...
abort_self_signal:
  ADD SP, SP, #32
  LDR X2, [SP, #16]
  LDR X0, [SP], #32
  BR X0
```

This is so strange, the branch target is just [several instructions behind](https://github.com/beehive-lab/mambo/blob/master/arch/aarch64/dispatcher_aarch64.S#L291). And there is no any other reference for this label.

Can I replace the `CBZ` instruction with `BR` without any label in ASM?

I use clang with compile option `-fno-integrated-as`, so the assembler is `GAS`.

Comment: What TEXTREL issue exactly?  Future readers with the same problem would be more easily able to find this if you quoted an error message.  Is it to do with the branch target being too far away at link time?  Normally you wouldn't have a TEXTREL at all, though, since the branch displacement would be a link-time constant, unless they're in different shared objects.

Comment: Kinda, `cbz` could be replaced with `cmp` + `b.eq`. You have to validate that `x0` contains valid address. Otherwise `br x0` in `abort_self_signal` would jump to zero address (which might sort of reset). But commonly, such things are fixed with linker script.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have put more details for the question, could you take your time to see again?

Comment: @user3124812 `b.eq` also need a branch lable, the problem still exists. Can I make a branch with a numeric offset?

Comment: The TEXTRELs are pretty clearly for the `.word   0x00003f8c` and `.word 0x000052f8` absolute addresses which are loaded with `ldr`, which seems unrelated to the `cbz` you showed in the asm source.   Presumably with PC-relative loads, not SP-relative loads that the source for `abort_self_signal:` uses.  The instructions you showed from objdump output are all discontiguous, and the first three are totally unrelated, just happening to have `7d2[08]` in the low bits of the instruction word, not their own address.  So that's pretty confusing to wade through.

Comment: heh... you could... but that sounds fishy. If I got your question right that would be `"mov x0, .", "add x0, x0, #8", "br x0"`. Meaning: Load current instruction address to register, add required offset, branch to offsetted address. Or you could load any other known address as a base for offset.